# Moment js determine how many days, weeks has passed

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, datetime-format, relative-time-span

I'm not really good at handling **datetime**. I used [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for a **ionic app** for manipulating time but I want to achieve something that I couldn't.

I used a pipe for that and I want to display based on if how many days have been passed or if weeks and months or years. Using **relative time** would help me that like the `fromNow()` method and the `calendar()` of **momentjs**. But in my case I would have multiple `conditions`.

Here is the sample code below of my pipe

```
transform(value: Date | moment.Moment, dateFormat: string): any {
    if (moment(value) < moment(value).subtract(7, 'days')) {
      return moment(value).format('llll') // Use this format if weeks, months or years has passed
    } else if (moment(value) < moment(value).subtract(1, 'days')) {
      return moment(value).calendar(); // Use calendar time if 1 day has passed
    } else {
      return moment(value).fromNow(); // Use relative time if within 24 hours
    }
  }
```

If seconds, minutes or hours has passed until 24 hours I will use the `fromNow()` method but when days passed I will use the `calendar()` and if weeks, months or years passed use this `format('llll')`.

Can someone shed some light for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Please elaborate it

Comment: @VicJordan edited it. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to take a decision based on *how long ago* a particular moment was from `now`. It seems like you have 3 cases: > 7 days, > 1day, <1day.

Momentjs provides a very useful `diff` method. So, you could do something like:

```
  var currDate = moment.now();
  var dateToTest = moment(val);
  // if dateToTest will always be in past, use currDate as the base to diff, else 
  be prepared to handle the negative outcomes. 
  var result = currDate.diff(dateToTest, 'days')
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Test Cases: ")
  console.log("Input: Date is 2 minutes behind")
  dateThing("2018-07-20T12:02:54+00:00");
  
  console.log("Input: Date is few hours behind")
  dateThing("2018-07-20T07:02:54+00:00");
  
  console.log("Input: Date is 23 hours 59 minutes behind")
  dateThing("2018-07-19T12:03:54+00:00");
  
  console.log("Input: Date is 24 hours behind")
  dateThing("2018-07-19T12:04:54+00:00");
  
  console.log("Input: Date is 2 days behind")
  dateThing("2018-07-18T12:04:54+00:00");
  
  console.log("Input: Date is 12 days behind")
  dateThing("2018-07-08T12:04:54+00:00");
}

dateThing = function(val) {
  // for now freezing the "now" so that precise testcases can be written.
  // var currDate = moment.now();
  var currDate = moment("2018-07-20T12:04:54+00:00")
  var dateToTest = moment(val);
  // if dateToTest will always be in past, use currDate as the base to diff, else be prepared to handle the negative outcomes. 
  var result = currDate.diff(dateToTest, 'days')
  if (result > 7) {
    console.log("Output: date is more than 1 week behind")
  } else if (result > 1) {
    console.log("Output: date is more than 1 day but less than 1 week behind")
  } else {
    console.log("Output: date is less  than 1 day behind")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Please run the above snippet to see the behaviour for border cases, if it isn't accurate, you can go for diff with minutes and reverse the flow.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I want to! Thank you. I just didn't dive the docs carefully because of its large scope. But hey if you really want to use it. Then dig it deeper. Thanks

Comment: how could I return this with real time update each second? I tried adding a setInterval in the return value but it said that unexpected identifier like this `return setInterval(moment(value).format('llll'), 1000) // Use this format if weeks is passed`

Comment: you'll have to call the entire function in your `setInterval`, for e.x. if your function is `something(inputDate)`, you'll need to wrap the entire function call: `setInterval(something(inputDate), 1000)` be careful about clearing the interval and ensuring that your inputDate variable isn't lost, I don't know about ionic framework, but there are various Javascript concepts you can use to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

There you go. :)

```js
function transformDate(givenDate) {
    if (moment().subtract(7, 'days').valueOf() > moment(givenDate).valueOf()) {
      return moment(givenDate).format('llll');
    } else if (moment().subtract(1, 'days').valueOf() > moment(givenDate).valueOf()) {
      return moment(givenDate).calendar();
    } else {
      return moment(givenDate).fromNow();
    }
}
// current time
console.log(transformDate(new Date()));
// 8 days before this answer was posted 
console.log(transformDate(new Date(1531394211385))); 
// 2 days before this answer was posted
console.log(transformDate(new Date(1531912692803)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```